# SMS Broadcastreceiver not working

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I discovered that when GO SMS or other similar applications that use SMS  are installed on an Android mobile, SMS Broadcastreceiver is not called.

Should I remove all that applications in order to receive a message?

What will be the highest priority for Broadcastreceiver intent?

As far as I know, this is the Priority of GO SMS Pro app android:priority="2147483747"

Comment: You can't just throw out "it does not work" like that. Give more details, give code, give manifest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing GOSMS app first then you install your own application then that will work . GOSMS app has the highest priority which can be set for any app .

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps it will work:
1 - Launch GoSMS app on your Android phone
2 - Under 'Menu -> Settings -> Receive Settings' - uncheck the box that says 'Disable other message notification'